# Hide some items in a foreach loop with a show more button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using a foreach loop in my php like this

```
<div class="items">
@foreach($results as $details)
<div class="col s2 l2">
{{ $details }}
</div></div>
```

I am just using the blade templating provided by Laravel.

How can I only show the first line of the resulted items, that is, only 6 items first, as 6 items will equal 12 rows, as each items takes 2 rows (according to flexbox) and show a `showmore` button which on click will show all the items

I tried changing the height of `items` div but this hides the whole div on clicking show more. I figured, that is not the best way to do it, can anyone guide me how should I do this?

Comment: what's coming in from $details?

Comment: From `$details` I am getting times, like `9:00` `10:00` and so on

Comment: so what is the actual HTML you're getting, once Laravel has passed the HTML to the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your missing *endforeach*.The $results is array? or instance of a class?

```
<div class="items">
@foreach($results as $details)
<div class="col s2 l2">
{{ $details }}
</div>
@endforeach
</div>
```